# How to display the main menu when Dock icon is hidden?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, menu, uielement

I developed a basic menubar app. How do you hide the dock icon and still have the Main Menu display when menubar app (status-item) is active?

Note: The Main Menu only displays If the dock icon is not hidden.

e.g. Main Menu (File, Edit, View etc at the left of the menu bar)

[image]

Comment: I may misunderstand the question, but it is bad style to have an app with a menubar but without an dock icon. Pure status bar applications should only offer a status item at the right side of the menubar. To hide the dock icon for such apps lookup the documentation for the key `NSUIElement` in `Info.plist`.

Comment: To elaborate on what @mschmidt wrote, status-item apps (`LSUIElement`=1) do not appear in the dock and they _cannot_ display a menubar. (see `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`) The only menu you can provide is by installing a status-item menu which appears on the right. If you have menu commands, put them there.